# Manually change MAC address on USB to ethernet module Pi Zero

Tags: networking, raspbian-stretch, ethernet, pi-zero, ethernet-port

Very unusual request here, I know you aren't normally meant to change your MAC address since it's burned into the interface you are using, but I am networking 2 raspberry Pi zeros together, each with a USB to ethernet attachment where the manufacturer used the EXACT SAME mac address for both modules. So now I need to manually change one.

I've read a lot of instruction saying to do that through `/etc/network/interfaces` but I've also read that using that file is now totally outdated so there ought to be a more correct way of making this change. Would that be through `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` - and if so what is the command to be written?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

based in information found [here](https://upon2020.com/blog/2017/07/how-to-change-your-ethernets-mac-address-on-boot-linux/)

```
sudo tee /etc/systemd/network/00-default.link <<EOF
[Match]
MACAddress=00:00:00:00:00:00

[Link]
MACAddress=00:00:00:00:00:01
EOF
```

replace `00:00:00:00:00:00` with your USB/Ethernet MAC address and `00:00:00:00:00:01` with whatever you want your MAC to be

As for what to set the address to, something in the "locally administered" ranges are probably the safest, these are

```
x2-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
x6-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
xA-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
xE-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
```

I have tested the above on a Raspberry pi 3, so can not guarantee it will work with a USB ethernet dongle - however, since the article I linked to refers to `cute little USB-to-Ethernet adapters for your Raspberry Pi Zeros` I'm fairly confident this should work for you

Comment: You're the most helpful guy around @Jaromanda x

Comment: Just good timing, @Matt. I was looking at using USB-Ethernet adapters for a couple of my Zero's - your question made me wonder if ALL such adapters had similar issues. So, in a way, your question helped me before I even (possibly) had the same issue (oh, and I see I've answered you before :p )

Comment: Well it works to change the MAC address if I will know the MAC address. So `eth0` is static in my case. But the usb to ethernet module has also `eth1` and `eth2`. I don't know how this could work if I won't find out how `eth1` and `eth2` changes. In other words: I can not use `eth0`. And I can only replace (MATCH and LINK) if I will know the original MAC of `eth1` or `eth2`.

Comment: well, you have two mac addresses on the USB device, right ... pick 1 make it eth1, pick the other make it eth2 - if it's not the order you want, swap ... it's not clear from the answer, but you can create multiple files in that folder ... say `10-eth1.link` and `00-eth2.link`